# How to close toggled div when another div is triggered

Tags: jquery

I'm creating slide out panels for menu items so when one button is clicked a panel slides out. What I need is a way to make the opened panel close when another button is clicked to open a different panel. Here's what I have.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
$(".trigger").click(function(){
            $(this).prev('.panel').toggle("fast");
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
    return false;
});
  });
</script>
<div id="menu-filter">
 <div class="panel">
<-----content A----->
 </div>
 <a class="trigger" href="#">A</a>

 <div class="panel">
<-----content B----->
 </div>
 <a class="trigger" href="#">B</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Create a jsfiddle and I'm sure several of us will take a look!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for me this makes things a little easier
wrap each panel/button in a container div

```
<div id="menu-filter">
  <div class="panel-container">
    <div class="panel">
      <-----content A----->
    </div>
    <a class="trigger" href="#">A</a>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-container">
    <div class="panel">
      <-----content B----->
    </div>
    <a class="trigger" href="#">B</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

then

```
$(".trigger").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  // clicked button
  var $button = $(this);
  // get ref to panel, go up to parent container and back down to find panel
  var $panel = $(this).closest("panel-container").find("panel");

  if ($button.hasClass("active")) {
    // we hide the open panel for this button
    $panel.hide("fast");
    $button.removeClass("active");
  } else {
    // hide any open panels
    $('.panel').hide("fast");
    $('.trigger').removeClass("active");

    // show clicked
    $panel.toggle("fast");
    $button.toggleClass("active");
  }
});
```

using closest and find can allow the markup to change later without breaking the javascript, however if you had 1000s of panels it might not perform so well

this code has not been tested

Comment: doh..and the answer was so easy. Thanks!

Comment: actually one problem..this no longer destroys the panel of the trigger got it clicked. So the trigger is clicked and then the panel slides out but if you click that same trigger again it just reloads the panel.

Comment: so the behavior you want is trigger click opens a panel; clicking that panel again or clicking another trigger will close it?

Comment: Oh when you declared the $panel variable you left out the periods for the classes. It works great with that edit! Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

maybe this will help : http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/, you'll have to handle some function in case you click another button to open a different panel

Best